# How to allow some specific device to connect to TL-WR841N first

Tags: wireless-access-point

I set up an access point using TL-WR841N.
It seems like the maximum connection is around 15.
But the IoT devices need to have connection first, then the guest can join the network.
Can I set up some rules to let some devices connect to AP first?

Edit: when the connection reach 15, the normal device should be disconnected and let prioritized device connect instead when the prioritized device tried to connect.

Comment: How would it know that it should deny a connection because another prioritized device will connect in 30 seconds?

Comment: Umm... Sorry, I didn't explain well. Connecting order depends on the IoT devices and guests. But could I disconnect a normal device and let a prioritized device connect instead, when prioritized device try to connect?